# could not find a version that satisfies the requirement jdcal

Tags: python, python-3.x

i have created a virtual environment for python for developement. I need module openpyxl for my work. first i have downloaded .tar.gz file then i am using the command pip install repo/openpyxl-2.5.6 tar.gz where 'repo" is directory where i have kep my .tar.gz file .. After using this error i am getting the following error-

```
[venv] sccj019251> pip install repo/openpyxl-2.5.6.tar.gz
Processing ./repo/openpyxl-2.5.6.tar.gz
Collecting jdcal (from openpyxl==2.5.6)
Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, 
status=None)) after connection broken by 
'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection 
object at 0x7fc0f1ecccf8>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect 
timeout=15)')': /simple/jdcal/
Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, 
status=None)) after connection broken by 
'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection 
object at 0x7fc0f1ea6320>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect 
timeout=15)')': /simple/jdcal/
Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, 
status=None)) after connection broken by 
'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection 
object at 0x7fc0f1ea65c0>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect 
timeout=15)')': /simple/jdcal/
Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, 
status=None)) after connection broken by 
'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection 
object at 0x7fc0f1ea6dd8>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect 
timeout=15)')': /simple/jdcal/
Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, 
status=None)) after connection broken by 
'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection 
object at 0x7fc0f1ea66a0>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect 
 timeout=15)')': /simple/jdcal/
 Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement jdcal (from 
 openpyxl==2.5.6) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for jdcal (from openpyxl==2.5.6)
```

please tell me how to resolve this error

Comment: Looks like pip can't connect to pypi.org.  Are you behind a corporate firewall or proxy, or does your internet just suck?

Comment: Yes I am connected with my Company's network because i am working on a project where i need a virtual env-@ jwodder